# Converting a pointer to a double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I would like to call a method with the following signature.

```c
error (*handler)(obj **, const char *, void*)
```

Because the `context` variable is a pointer, it needs to be converted to a pointer to a pointer. However, doing it the following way throws the compile error `gfserver.c:185:20: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘gfcontext_t {aka struct gfcontext_t}’)`. How can this pointer be converted to a double pointer?

```c
obj *context = (obj *)malloc(sizeof(obj)); 
m->handler(**context, request, handlerarg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)`  is exactly equal to `p[i]`. From that follows that `*p` is equal to `p[0]`.

Put into the context (pun not intended) of your question, `**context` would then be equal to `context[0][0]` which makes no sense.

It seems you should use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to the pointer. As in `&context`.